# Django admin add form show object fields from related model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have following model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Company", max_length=200)


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Department", max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Employee(models.Model):

    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to have my Add employee admin form have besides Department, related selection for Company.

So when i select Company i get choice of its departments.

Currently i get choice of all the departments.

App is heavily admin focused so it would be good to have this functionality.

Comment: what django version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Django 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using django autocomplete light. Here are the [docs](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-in-the-admin).

This will give you the functionality to display options in the child filter based on the selection in parent filter with the help of its `forward` paramater.

Create a form class with custom company field and then forward the field to department filter as:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(), 
                                 widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='your_company_auto_url'),
                                 required=False)
    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Department.objects.all(),
                                    widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='your_department_auto_url',
                                                                     forward=['company']))

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

Department View:

```
class DepartmentAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return Department.objects.none()

        qs = Department.objects.all()

        company = self.forwarded.get('company', None)

        if company:
            qs = qs.filter(company=company)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

This will forward the selected `company` id and it can then be used in the autocomplete view to filter the department queryset. Please refer to the documentation to create autocomplete views to be used for the fields in the form.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

IMO,perhaps you need to change "Klijent" to "Company",I wonder what is the "Klijent" use for?

Comment: It was translation error for this post, good catch corrected it now.